# Who is the fifth child?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Jason's mother has five children. The first one is July. The second one is August. The third one is September. The fourth one is October. What is the fifth child's name?

Comment: @mmking Duplicate of what? ;-)

Comment: That question got deleted, so I found another one: possible duplicate of [What was her name?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/what-was-her-name)

Comment: @mmking Frankly, I wish I could delete that one as well. I actually think this one is better, but I'm not sure what the policy is in such a case: maybe we could close the old one as a dupe of the new one?

Comment: OK, I've voted to close the old one (score -15) as a dupe of this. Let's see where that takes us...

Comment: @rand al'thor Quick question, if these are supposedly the same, should the NEWEST one not be closed as a DUPLICATE of the old one?

Comment: @warspyking Normally, yes; but I thought this one was better than the older one! I'm pretty sure that VTCing the older one is 'the done thing' in these circumstances?

Comment: @rand al'thor This is STILL the duplicate. I didn't duplicate anything because mine came first. Not the other way around. Even if this one IS better, mine came first and has the title as the original. Unless you think I have fortune teller powers and that I duplicated a future post? If that is the case, I really need to learn to harness my powers.

Comment: @warspyking there's no "has the title" to it. When two questions cover the same ground, either might be closed as a dupe of the other. Often it's based on the quality of the answers. It's even possible for mods to merge answers that were posted on one question over to the other if both questions have good answers. System wide, old questions can be and are closed as dupes of newer questions.

Comment: @warspyking Check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fifth child is

> Jason

Reason:

> Jason's four siblings have been described. That means that the fifth one, the one remaining, is Jason.

Answer (score 27):

The initials of July, August, September, October, and November spell Jason. Therefore the seemingly-right answer of November, which we reject because we're told she's Jason's mother, can in fact be right if "Jason" is the family nickname for all the children the way "the girls" or "the rugrats" is in some families.

Comment: This is ... brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

> Since the question states that **Jason**'s mother has five children, the fifth must be named Jason.