# Logical English Riddles

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, english

> Someone's mother has four sons. name of three sons are
>   **north**,**east**,**west**, what is the name of the fourth son

can anyone tell?

Comment: Poor kids... Why would you name them like that.

Comment: @North is offended, PL457 :-)

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/169/).

Comment: @PL457 To create the NEWS(outh) ;P

Comment: @ABcDexter and others who closed that post: According to the accepted answer, this is not a duplicate of [Who is the fifth child?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17389/32339). It is rather a duplicate of [Say the name of the mother's son](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56633/32339) (I flagged the post again for moderator intervention)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i believe that the answer is

> What

as

> whenever this question is asked, it’s actually asked this way: “Someone's mom has four sons, North, East and West. What is the name of the fourth son. Can you guess the name of the fourth son?”

moreover

> If you read it again, the second sentence ends with a full stop. It’s a statement. It tells you the name of the fourth son is, “What”.

Comment: He does have a point. title says logical english riddles. Didn't even begin to think about that +1

Comment: So, 'Someone' must be the name of a daughter?

Answer (score 10):

I believe the answer is:

> Someone?